# prestashop module showing Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given

Tags: php, arrays, prestashop

I am doing a custom module in prestashop. Now in my php file I have the function like

```
 public function hookHome($params)
  {
    $defaultLanguage = (int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
    global $cookie, $smarty;
    $value=array();
    $sql_select="SELECT DISTINCT country_name,country_ISO from "._DB_PREFIX_."storedetails where status='1'";
       $result=Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql_select);
       print_r($result);

      while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
      {
      $value[] = $row;
  }
       $smarty->assign('array',$value);
       $smarty->assign('default',$defaultLanguage);
     return $this->display(__FILE__, 'storedetails.tpl');
  }
```

The concept behind this piece of code is storing all the values in an array, and get them in view file(smarty template).

Here when I am doing print_r($result); it is showing the array. The values are coming like this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [country_name] => [country_ISO] => select ) [1] => Array ( [country_name] => Germany [country_ISO] => DE )...
```

but from next line it is showing error like `Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in filename.php line number`

In my .tpl file(view file) I have the code where I would like to get the values like

```
<select onchange="selectCountry(this.value)">
    <option value="Select">Select</option> 
     {foreach from=$array item=row}
         <option value="{$row.country_ISO}" id="{$row.country_name}">{$row.country_name}</option>
    {/foreach}
    </select>
```

So can someone kindly tell me why I am getting this error and how to solve this issue?Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: whatever prestashop is doing with that `->execute()` call, it's NOT returning a mysql result handle. you cannot feed anything BUT a result handle to mysql_fetch, and probably shouldn't even be trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here directly assign your `$result` to `smarty template`. Because it is already in `array` format.

```
$smarty->assign('array',$result);
```

`mysql_fetch_assoc` is used to iterate the result of `SELECT` query, but in your situation your are giving `array` as input not the `resource` of `SELECT` query.